# Is there a more concise way to write the assign for this wire in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

Just trying to create a wire `finished` that is true iff `data == dataNew` for all registers and indexes.  The only way I can come up with is using a bunch of `finishedAgg` wires as intermediate values; I'd love to get rid of them but I can't figure out how to.  Seems like there *has* to be an easier way than this!

```
reg[24:0] data[0:24];
reg[24:0] dataNew[0:24];

wire finished;

genvar i;
generate
    wire finishedAgg[-1:24];
    assign finishedAgg[-1] = 1;
    for (i=0; i<25; i=i+1) begin :b1
        assign finishedAgg[i] = finishedAgg[i-1] & (data[i]==dataNew[i]);
    end
    assign finished = finishedAgg[24];
endgenerate
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my cut at it:

```
reg [24:0] finishAgg;
wire finished;
always @(*)
    for (int i=0; i<25; i=i+1) begin :b1
        finishedAgg[i] = (data[i]==dataNew[i]);
    end : b1
assign finished = &finishedAgg;
```

It's not too much shorter than your version, but it doesn't need a `generate` block. I've declared `i` in-loop Systemverilog-style, and I'm using a reduction-AND to make the `finished` signal.

Comment: I was surprised to see that this compiles down to the exact same reg count and gate count.  I'm a Verilog newbie and a little freaked out about putting regs in there that don't actually compile to regs; it makes it look like something it's not.  Is this common practice?

Comment: It's very common practice, welcome to verilog! `reg` doesn't necessarily compile to a flip-flop or latch, it depends how it's used.